# Inverse of Fourier transform gives "data type not supported" error

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, fft, opencv3.0

I am trying to implementing the inverse of Fourier transform. Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np 
import cv2 as cv
import math 
import cmath
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
image="test2.bmp" 
img=cv.imread(image,cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
#foruior transform 
dft = cv.dft(np.float32(img),flags = cv.DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT)
#shifting for displaying 
dft_shift = np.fft.fftshift(dft)
#get the filter contains real and complex part 
t=1
a=0.1 
b=0.1
motion_filter=np.empty((img.shape[0],img.shape[1],2),dtype=np.complex_)
for x in range(img.shape[0]):
    for y in range(img.shape[1]):
        if x==0 and y==0:
            const1=math.pi*(1e-10)
        else:
            const1=math.pi*((x*a)+(y*b)) 
        #for real number
        motion_filter[x,y,0]=((t/const1)*(math.sin(const1))*(cmath.exp((0-1j)*(const1)))).real
        #for complex number
        motion_filter[x,y,1]=((t/const1)*(math.sin(const1))*(cmath.exp((0-1j)*(const1)))).imag
#processing
fshift = dft_shift*motion_filter
#shift back 
f_ishift = np.fft.ifftshift(fshift)
#inverse 
img_back = cv.idft(f_ishift)
#take real part 
img_back=img_back[:,:,0]
#show image 
plt.imshow(img_back,cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

And the error occurs when doing:

```
img_back = cv.idft(f_ishift)
```

The error message is:

> src data type = 15 is not supported

How can I fix the code?

Comment: Did you try to search on SO before posting the question? **Exact** (not possible) Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30989915/typeerror-src-data-type-15-is-not-supported

Comment: Not working . I tried before

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: src data type = 15 is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30989915/typeerror-src-data-type-15-is-not-supported)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the answer in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30989915/typeerror-src-data-type-15-is-not-supported), the OpenCV `idft` requires a real-valued matrix where the real and imaginary components are stored along a third dimension. You create this matrix:

```
motion_filter=np.empty((img.shape[0],img.shape[1],2),dtype=np.complex_)
```

It is of the right sizes (2 along the 3rd dimension, for the real and imaginary components), but it is complex-valued. Next you multiply your Fourier-domain image (a real-valued matrix with real and imaginary components along the 3rd dimension) with this complex matrix, creating a complex-valued output:

```
fshift = dft_shift*motion_filter
```

This complex-valued output cannot be used in `cv.idft`. Instead, create your filter matrix as a real-valued matrix:

```
motion_filter=np.empty((img.shape[0],img.shape[1],2))
```

Comment: Am I doing the correct way to store the real part and complex part for kernel?

Comment: @kris: Looks correct to me, but I haven't tried running your code. But you are computing that complex value twice, which is not efficient.